# MYSQL - Which Enum Perform better Enum('Y','N') or Enum('1','0')

Tags: mysql, enums, query-performance

I have a very big MYSQL Table containing 800000 records. I want to know which type performance is better Enum('male','female') or Enum(1,0) based on following parameters

1. Storage
2. Query performance - It's like when I will use

   ```
   SELECT cols FROM table WHERE type = 'female'
   or
   SELECT cols FROM table WHERE type = 0
   ```

Then which one perform better or there is any other way to handle this situation ?

Comment: The storage and performance should be the same. You might want to read this article about the use of enums though: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ Maybe using an enum isn't the best choice. The alternative would be to store types in a separate table and use foreign keys and joins instead, which might be better for data integrity.

Comment: ok, but as per my knowledge; using '1' in where clause will perform better that using 'Y'; isn't it ?

Comment: @JatinSeth: Why would that be the case?

Comment: 800000 rows is nothing. Besides, you could test this in less time than it takes to ask and answer this question.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to discuss the facts with geniuses out there :)

Comment: So you think that changing a column value will improve performance? Why is that? Why do you think that and why do you ask the question about a column and not about how to make your db and query work faster? Classic XY problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no difference at all.

Enums are encoded as numbers, so the result is the same for both your examples.

If anything, you should compare using some kind of enum versus using a varchar, bit, or numeric column (maybe range-enforced by a constraint).

Comment: Yes. Enums are encoded as numbers. The name you give your enum options does not matter. In the table and the indexes, the column value is stored as 0, 1, 2, ....

Comment: Yes, you are very right but can you please let me know why performance increased when I used TINYINT instead of ENUM, curios to know how Mysql handles these.

Comment: Unlikely that TINYINT has a significant performance difference. If you are interested in that, post a new question and be sure to include your complete observations (including the outputs of the explain query commands).

Comment: `TINYINT` may have run faster due to some coincidence with what was cached when you ran your test.  Did you run each one twice?   And with the Query cache disabled (`SQL_NO_CACHE`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this thing in MYSQL and my findings are given below:

1. There is no difference in performance when we are comparing ENUM('male','female') with ENUM('1','0')

Comment: Same query took 0.124 seconds with ENUM and 0.072 seconds with TINYINT while checking for 8 lac records.